# how to access local GPIO from remote Django/apache server

Tags: gpio, python, web-server, web-browsers

how can i get a local event (example: a physical button pressed) to trigger events on a remote django website.

without using a keyboard or mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

@lenik is right.

Another way is just use Python: write a Python script (or even better, a Django project) to send a HTTP request (I would use JSON or REST API) to the Django remote application. Sounds too much work, and it is if the purpose is just for fun. But it's way more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to do things the other way around.

the correct way would be to write a `python` script to use `GPIO` library to access the current state of your pins and then if something interesting happens, use `urllib` to access the remote URL, thus telling your web server about the remote events.